# Android app to load any specified app on boot

Tags: gratis, android, boot

Looking for an app that will load a user-specified app every time an Android (KitKat) device boots.

For example, maybe you want to run 'My Favorite App' every time your Android device boots.  Looking for an app that would allow the user to specify 'My Favorite App' one time, and then automatically run it every time the system boots.

Very simple.  Nothing fancy.  Nothing extravagant like Tasker.

Sort of like a simple autoexec.bat, if you remember DOS.

*Requirements:*

- Free of cost.
- No ads.
- No processes always running.
- No internet access.
- No unneeded permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow.  It's amazing that Google's main product is a search engine, yet the search functionality on their own Google Play Store is so horrible.

After hours of searching, I finally found the exact app that meets the above requirements.

It's called Autorun and the link is [here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fit009c.autorun)

Many thanks to the author of that perfectly simple app.

I hope this helps others save some time!